# Как вынести значение z из промиса, почему не получается его вывести после получения Promise.all()?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElements(By.css("div#box-campaigns.box s.regular-price"))  
.then(result => result.map(z => z.getCssValue(["color"]))) 
.then(res =>Promise.all(res) 
.then(z => console.log(z)) );
```

нужно будет сравнить значение Z с результатом другого промиса
но как получить это значение, чтобы с ним можно было работать?

PS. с промисами до этого вообще дел не имел, но очень хочу разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в последнем then поместить еще один промис:

```
driver.findElements(By.css("div#box-campaigns.box s.regular-price"))  
  .then(result => result.map(z => z.getCssValue(["color"]))) 
  .then(res => Promise.all(res))
  .then(z => {
    // Вы хотите работать с полученой z, она доступна тут(в этом теле функции)
    // Вот пример как использовать промис с использованием z
    myPromise(z).then(result => {
      // результат промиса
    })
  });
```

Можно написать функцию которая возвращает промис с z:

```js
function getZ () {
  return driver.findElements(By.css("div#box-campaigns.box s.regular-price"))  
    .then(result => result.map(z => z.getCssValue(["color"]))) 
    .then(res => Promise.all(res))
}

getZ().then(z => {
  // тут доступна z
});
```

[Вот хорошая статься по промисам.](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

Comment: Там не так написал, второй точно должен работать, просто в then пишите еще один промис

Comment: наружу то вы можете, например, записать хоть в глобальный объект window, но там будет доступно только после выполнения промиса. То есть вы обратитесь к переменной до тогог как промис выполнится, то будет undefined. Если Вам надо получать значение z не только в одном месте, то можно сделать функциию(обновил ответ) которая возвращает промис с z.

Comment: Я пытаюсь сравнить значения получаемые промисами с двух разных страниц. Кроме как сохранить одно из значений ничего пока не придумал. Если есть другие варианты, то пожалуйта подскажите.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Чтобы передать данные на другую страницу можно использовать localStorage. Сначала выполняете промис на одной странице, полученный результат записуете в локальное хранилище, дальше это хранилище надо как-то отследить что оно изменилось на другой странице, самый простой вариант - сделать setInterval и там проверять на изменение, если изменилось, то запускать второй промис. Есть еще вариант отслеживать вот так хранилище: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768359/5286034. [Вот получше пример.](https://html5demos.com/storage-events/#view-source)

Comment: ваш второй вариант работает! теперь как сравнить результаты работы двух промисов?

Comment: С селениумом не работал, та и опыта с тестами мало, если у Вас промисы в одном скрипте, то можно как в первом коде: вызывается промис, поле выполнения в then выдается результат с которым можно работать, прямо там в then вызываете другой промис.

Comment: и можно будет прямо в промис вставить переход на другую страницу для получения данных и потом сравнить?

Comment: если переход на другую страницу и есть промис, то да, можно так, это же nodejs,  там это как в одном скрипте. То есть Вам надо строить огромные цепочки then, но это уже "ад колбеков", если испльзуете node 10 то можно испольсовать очень классные async/await.

Comment: или поддержка даже с 7.6 версии

Comment: К сожалению нет возможности, только в чате, можем на фейсбуке.

Comment: Я тоже есть на фейсбуке, но никогда им не пользуюсь, как Вас найти там?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011474418562

Comment: кстати в послднем коде была маленькая ошибка, только щас заметил